# CakePHP: SQL Query to Cake->find()

Tags: sql, cakephp

Firstly, here's my [database relation diagram](http://uploads.navale.nl/vsa22-database.pdf).

I'm trying to make a diagram with the number of a certain element ordered for each day

```
date       | count
2011-04-22 | 10348
2011-04-23 | 2751
```

Since I'm more familiar with SQL, I've that that first, and this is what finally came out (and works)

```
 SELECT dn.delivery_date, SUM(dnp.count*ep.count) as count
 FROM
 `delivery_notes` AS dn JOIN `delivery_notes_products` AS dnp
    ON dn.id = dnp.delivery_note_id
 JOIN `products` AS p
    ON dnp.product_id = p.id
 JOIN `elements_products` AS ep
    ON p.id = ep.product_id
 JOIN `elements` AS e
    ON ep.element_id = e.id
 WHERE e.id = 4
   AND dn.delivery_date BETWEEN '2011-04-22' AND '2011-05-22'
 GROUP BY dn.delivery_date
```

Now to <strike>improve my</strike> get some Cake-find skills, I'm trying to understand how to turn this into a find('list') or find('all') query, yet I really have NO idea how I should tackle this one...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I personally had to do this by calling several finds. Never got it working with one single find. To implement this as a single sql query I would suggest to create a function in a model, that does precisely this query.

Comment: Thanks! Already did that though, was just wondering if there was a more 'Cakier' way of doing it ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->DeliveryNote->bindModel(array(
    'hasOne'=>array(
        'DeliveryNotesProduct'=>array(
            'conditions'=>array('DeliveryNotesProduct.DeliveryNoteId = DeliveryNote.id')
        ),
        'Product'=>array(
            'conditions'=>array('DeliveryNotesProduct.ProductId = Product.id')
        ),
        'ElementsProduct'=>array(
            'conditions'=>array('ElementsProduct.ProductId  = Product.id')
        ),
        'Element'=>array(
            'conditions'=>array('ElementsProduct.ElementId  = Element.id')
        )

    )
));


$data = $this->DeliveryNote->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'Element.id'=>4,
        'DeliveryNote.DeliveryDate BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array('2011-04-22','2011-05-22')),
    'fields'=>array('DeliveryNote.DeliveryDate','SUM(DeliveryNotesProduct.Count * ElementsProduct.Count) AS count'),
    'group'=>array('DeliveryNote.DeliveryDate')
));
```

Cakephp `bindModel` is used for joining tables and `hasOne` is one of the association type
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1040/Relationship-Types

Comment: Just tried it, gives me weird SQL errors though... (Even after unbinding other models)
    `SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Product.delivery_note_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Product.delivery_note_id ; I haven't use it in whole query .. there might be some other problem ... Take a look at all of your models ( that are included in query ), I think this problem is related to your model .

Comment: That's the weird thing, I've unbound all models beforehand...
Nevertheless, thanks to your link I found http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables, and that got it to work ;)